# Dual Monitor Resolution problem

Tags: dual-boot, hdmi, dualhead

Whenever I plug in my second monitor, which is my tv that I plug in using HDMI, the screen zooms in really far, and I can only access about half of the desktop. I have windows on my other hard drive on the computer, and the dual monitors runs fine with it, but Ubuntu screws it up. I had to unplug the drive that had Ubuntu on it, because it even caused my bios to be zoomed in really far, and therefore useless. Does anyone know a way I could fix this?

Comment: We need more information. Please edit the question to include what kind of graphics card your computer has. Are you using the built-in drivers, or have you installed any proprietary drivers? If you have installed any drivers for the video card, how did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Plug in your TV first then,

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type :

```
gnome-display-properties
```

Then

Check **Same image in both monitors**, that should do the trick.